# iterating through hierarchical structures in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, hierarchy

I have a set of numbered groups in a data set that are organized hierarchically. Each group has a numbered title and has several members of that group. For example:

```
01 : Tony, John, Meredith
01.01 : Alex, Fred, Melissa
02 : Alley, Henry, Natalie
02.01.02 : Chris, Pete
03 : Andrew
03.01 : Nancy, Peter, Harold
```

What data structure should I use in python to organize these groups? I need to maintain the hierarchy so that 01.01 is a child of 0.1. The structure of the data goes up to 7 levels deep such as: 01.03.01.01.02.04.05, this group is a child of the group 01.03.01.01.02.04, and so on. Any help is much appreciated. I am not sure what data structure to create so I can iterate over it. Thanks.

Comment: A linked list or tree, probably. You'll definitely need to make it yourself for that data, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask "What data structure should I use in python to organize these groups?"

A key principle of top-down programming is that you do not decide the implementation of an abstract data structure until you have decided the operations that will be done on the structure as well as their relative frequencies and any other criteria (such as simplicity and memory usage). You have not stated that information, so we cannot recommend a particular implementation.

I can think of many ways to do what you ask: a tree, lists within lists, dictionaries within dictionaries, etc. Each has its advantages and disadvantages. I do wonder about one point. In your structure, every item at a new sub-level begins with '01', with the exception of '02.01.02 : Chris, Pete' which begins with '02'. Is that intentional? If you keep the otherwise apparent numbering, that opens up some simpler implementations.

---

With the added information in your comment, I recommend nested lists. Each *data item* has a sequence of indices that ends in zero, and anything else in the structure is a list that holds other data items and lists. In your example, if we let the entire structure be named `a`, then item 01 is `a[1][0]`, item 01.01 is in `a[1][1][0]`, item 02.01.02 is in `a[2][1][2][0]`, and so on. This structure allows more items to be inserted later, so we can easily add item 01.01.01 without disturbing the other items. There is no need to store the item numbers in the structure: they are directly inferred from the position of the data items in the structure.

This implementation also allows the entire structure to have a data item, which has an empty item number and is stored in `a[0]`. A missing data item can be flagged by `None`, a blank item can be another empty item such as `''`. Here is code that shows your example structure and code that prints it out.

```
def print_structure(structure, level=''):
    """Iterate through a heirarchical data structure, printing the data
       items with their level numbers"""
    for i, item in enumerate(structure):
        if i == 0:
            # Process each data item appropriately
            if item is not None:
                print(level + ' : ' + str(item))
        else:
            new_level = format(i, '02')
            if level:
                new_level = level + '.' + new_level
            print_structure(item, new_level)


a = [None,
     ['Tony, John, Meredith',
      ['Alex, Fred, Melissa']],
     ['Alley, Henry, Natalie',
      [None,
       ['?'],
       ['Chris, Pete']]],
     ['Andrew',
      ['Nancy, Peter, Harold']]]

print_structure(a)
```

In this implementation, each of your "groups" is a string. I put the group `'?'` where you said a group exists but did not state just what it is, and I put `None` where you did not say a data item exists. To modify the processing of the structure, just change the two lines after the comment `Process each data item appropriately`. The printout from the above code is

```
01 : Tony, John, Meredith
01.01 : Alex, Fred, Melissa
02 : Alley, Henry, Natalie
02.01.01 : ?
02.01.02 : Chris, Pete
03 : Andrew
03.01 : Nancy, Peter, Harold
```

Saving to and restoring from JSON is easy. This should meet your needs, though there are some modifications that could be made to either structure or code, of course.

Comment: Rory, thanks for your response. Each sub level does, in fact, begin with 01. In the example you cite there is actually a '02.01.01' group. I was just trying to show different examples of children in the hierarchy. In terms of what I want to do with the data I want iterate over the structure once it is built and write a json file with the structure intact. I am pulling the data from a Database.

Comment: Rory, This answer is very thorough and much appreciated. Thank-you for taking the time. This will help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal is to produce a JSON-friendly structure you can write out, use nested dictionaries (or `OrderedDict` if the order of elements is important). It keeps things simple, and writing it out with json will be trivial. Each dictionary can have a key `members` (a list or set of the children directly assigned to it), and a key `subgroups` that is a list or dict of the sub-dictionaries. It's not hard to create since the titles of the parent groups are prefixes of the subgroups.